# What is happening to the files during the installation tripple "./configure, make, make install" ?

Tags: software-installation

One recurrent pattern of installation I learned is as following:

1. wget ......./program.tar.gz
2. tar xzf program.tar.gz
3. cd program
4. ./configure
5. make
6. make install

after step 2 (tar xzf program.tar.gz) the zipped programm tarball is unfolded into a set of grown up files. 
What is actually happening to these files on a file system level (or below) during the typical installation triple "./configure, make, make install" is executed one after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**./configure** - [Configure script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script)
Basicly the script consists of lines which are checking some details about the machine on which the software will be installed. The script checks for dependencies on the system. Software which will be installed may require a lot of things to exists on system. If any of requirements are missing on the system, the configure script will exit  and you can not proceed with installation, until you got those requirements. The configure script's main job is to create a file named Makefile to be used with make utility.

**make** - [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))
'make' actually exists on almost every *nix system. Make utility requires Makefile (sometimes it is makefile) in same directory in which you run make.
Basicly it compiles all your program code and create executables. The Makefile actually has a lot of labels (sort of names for different sections). If make ran successfully then you are almost done with the installation. Only the last step remains which is:

**make install**
As indicated before make uses the file named Makefile in the same directory. When you run make without any parameters, the instruction in the Makefile begin executing from the start and as per the rules defined within the Makefile (particular sections of the code may execute after one another, thats why labels are used, to jump from one section to another). But when you run make with install as the parameter, the make utility searches for a label named install within the Makefile, and executes only that section of the Makefile.
The install section happens to be only a part where the executables and other required files created during the last step (i.e. make) are copied into the required final directories on your machine (E.g /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, etc.).